# Inflate RecyclerView which is nested in a ContraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am running into an issue within my fragment where I am attempting to inflate a view and verify that it is a RecyclerView before initializing an adapter.

The issue is because the layout is not simply a RecyclerView component anymore, I have wrapped it in a ConstraintLayout and added a FloatingActionButton.

How can I inflate that specific part of the view, or what would be the best way to handle this issue where the adapter never gets initialized because of the `(view instanceof RecyclerView)` code.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_list, container, false);

Context context = view.getContext();
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;

if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

    mySearchRecyclerViewAdapter = new MySearchRecyclerViewAdapter(gameList, mListener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mySearchRecyclerViewAdapter);
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.scuvanov.weplay.fragment.SearchFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.scuvanov.weplay.fragment.SearchFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_search">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list)` ?

Comment: Thanks, the answer was staring me in the face.